# Two Teensy Microprocessor Connected via wire for digitalRead digitalWrite input, output not working

Tags: input, serialization, output, microprocessors, teensy

I'm stuck with the following issue, I want the LED matrix to only light up when the audio is playing from the first teensy (both 4.1) . . .
[Video of Issue! Unsure if the problem is in the code or the hardware](https://vimeo.com/826900848/211e89485c?share=copy)

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the code so that one teensy just toggles the pin and the other one prints out the pin state? I noticed also you seem to be connecting the pin to ground? If that ground rail on the breadboard is grounded (is connected to ground somewhere, maybe via the grey wire in your video), the pin will always ready low and driving the pin on the output high is a bad idea